# PNG quality looks horrible on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, png

I've created some avatars from vector artwork and saved them as transparent PNGs. If I place the PNGs in interface builder, the quality is perfect. When I place them using code, the edges are horribly jagged, as if the AA has been removed, yet it's the same image. Is there any way to place them with code and maintain nice smooth edges?

I've attached a screenshot below with the iphone ver on the right. 
[image]

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Did you save them as 24-bit PNGs with alpha channels?

Comment: It may also depend on the way you draw the image, e.g. using CoreGraphics or UIKit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple compresses `pngs` using a special optimization formula. It is possible that this formula is causing your images to alter from the original. If you notice a difference that you cannot live with, turn off the optimization by going into your `target`'s info panel and unchecking the `Compress PNG files` option under the `build` tab.
[image]

Comment: in my case , it's not helping .. here is my situation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500418/removing-jagged-edges-of-my-ropes-using-antialiasing-of-opengles    please help @coneybeare

Answer (score 0):

I have the same experience with this kind of situation.
Also when I change the hardware to iphone 4 it seems to be really good. so my suggestion to u is that unless u transfer ur app to iphone dont relay on the simulator.
You cannot really tell what will be the result on iphone by referring to simulator.

so dont panic, just check the image on iphone first before you get to any conclusion.

Comment: Oh that's a relief, I'll try it on my iPhone. Thanks!

Comment: While your answer is certainly true (you should test on the device to be sure) it is probably not the reason for the perceived quality loss