# removing jagged edges of my ropes using antialiasing of OpenGLES

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i have implemented ropes in which i have used Revolute joints to connect dynamic b2bodied , now i successfully created this ropes but my ropes not looking smoothy , i want them smooth just like ribbons . anyone having idea on this !! i found that it could be achieved by openGLES using anti-aliasing but still not getting idea that exactly how to achieve this ..  any kind of help would be appreciated .

my Rope is polygon shaped dynamic body , this way 
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position = currentPos;

```
b2PolygonShape polygonShape;
polygonShape.SetAsBox(linkWidth,linkHeight);

b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.density =20.0;

fixtureDef.shape = &polygonShape;

b2Body* link = world->CreateBody( &bodyDef );
link->CreateFixture( &fixtureDef );
```

Revolute Joint :

```
b2RevoluteJointDef revoluteJointDef;
revoluteJointDef.localAnchorA.Set( 0,  linkHeight);
revoluteJointDef.localAnchorB.Set( 0, -linkHeight);            
revoluteJointDef.bodyA = link;
revoluteJointDef.bodyB = lastLink;
world->CreateJoint( &revoluteJointDef );
```

please help .

i want my ropes smoother just like right most image

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

my output looks like this 
[image]

Comment: try Verlet Rope - http://cleverhamstergames.com/dev/verletRopeTestProject.zip

Comment: Thanks @Guru , but the link you provided is not working , it jus loading & loading ....

Comment: see bottom of this page..test project - http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2010/10/30/cocos2d-verlet-rope/

Comment: @GURU not working links dude .... anyway ..i want one recommendation from you .. can i achieve this using texture mapping .. means . i have used polygon shaped b2body & gives sprite to it ... can i do something like mapping texture on my polygon .. can u suggest something on this !

Comment: for me that link is working..may be ur's not open network...I used same verlet rope with texture..worked great

Answer (score 4):

You will have to enable multisampling if you want to get rid of the edges of textures. Multisampling will act on the entire screen and enabling it will have a performance penalty, most severely on older devices (iPhone 3GS).

Locate the line where CCGLView is instantiated in AppDelegate, and enable multi sampling and set the number of samples to 2 or 4.

```
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8    // <-- use whichever is your default
depthFormat:GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES // <-- use whichever is your default
preserveBackbuffer:NO
sharegroup:nil
multiSampling:YES    // <-- enable
numberOfSamples:4];  // <-- set to 2 or 4
```

One thing to keep in mind: **on Retina devices you won't be able to see the jagged edges** due to the high resolution of the display. Multisampling on Retina devices in a 2D app is likely a waste of performance and hardly increases image quality. That leaves you with another option: consider to just support Retina devices, or simply ignore that the issue exists on non-Retina devices because they're about to go away anyway.

Btw, the CCTexture2D aliasing and antialiasing methods are confusingly named, they do not perform full-screen or texture-edge aliasing or antialiasing. They change the texture's filtering mode between linear ("antialias", blurry) and nearest ("alias", no filtering).

The effect is that pixels within a texture are either linear filtered and thus individual pixel colors gradually change, whereas nearest filtering does not perform such filtering. Nearest filtering is most commonly needed for pixel art and tilemap tileset textures. Both only change filtering modes of the texture's pixels and not their edges. For that you need multisampling.

Comment: thank you very much for this information . as you told i saw my AppDelegate but i don't find  CCGLView , but  this . .    EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                 pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565 // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                 depthFormat:0   // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
     
   ];
still i tried with CCGLVIew  but i don't find CCGLView class even available in my appdelegate ... & when i am trying multisampling with my EAGLView then FPS showing 0.0 & screen goes full black ...now what to do bro ..!!!

Comment: If you have EAGLView use that, it just means you're on cocos2d 1.x and not 2.x.

Comment: ohwkey i have tries with : EAGLView . but it showing black screen with FPS 0.0 .  :(

Comment: i m having installed  cocos2d framework version 2.x. still why it's not showing me CCGLView class !! ?? any other problem !!!

Comment: i tried following code in my AppDelegate.m     
    EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds] 
                                    pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 
                                   depthFormat:0
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO 
                                    sharegroup:nil 
                                 multiSampling:YES 
                               numberOfSamples:4];       but its showing black screen with 0.0 FPS

Comment: please help ...i really stuck with this :(

Comment: have you tried with 2 samples? What happens if you create a new project with the same cocos2d version you're using, and enable multisampling in that project? If this also causes a black screen that may be version specific which means you'd have to upgrade cocos2d.

Comment: owk i have tried with it .. even with CCGLview class ... now FPS works fine but no changes to jaggerness .. it's there ..  i also tried with cocos2d v2 + box2d template .. still same result :(

Comment: MultiSampling not affecting the result of Jaggedness of my ribbon .i tried implementing it with new project too

Comment: is this possible for too much dynamic bodies i used with joints between them ?? so it may be given unpredictable behavior.  It could be possible because of dynamic bodies & my joints continuously moving because of my world simulation(scheduleUpdate >> step() method )  .. what you say ?? physics could play role in this jaggedness of Ribbon !!!

Comment: buddy, can u give some suggestion on this .. my work stopped because of this problem......