# removing aliasing of physic sprite ( b2body )

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have question relate to my this post .
    [removing jagged edges of my ropes using antialiasing of OpenGLES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500418/removing-jagged-edges-of-my-ropes-using-antialiasing-of-opengles)
i have searched lot on this but still not got any proper solution , i just want smooth edges of my physics sprite. is there any way to achieve this !!! . i also followed great Tutorial of http://www.raywenderlich.com/  but not helping me in my situation. please help

```
PhysicsSprite* segmentSprite = [PhysicsSprite spriteWithFile:@"red.png"];
[[segmentSprite texture] setAntiAliasTexParameters]; // try this one 
[[segmentSprite texture] setAliasTexParameters]; // try this one too        
[self addChild:segmentSprite];
```

Above code not helping.please help. how can i achieve this : Having smooth edges of my sprite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [removing jagged edges of my ropes using antialiasing of OpenGLES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500418/removing-jagged-edges-of-my-ropes-using-antialiasing-of-opengles)